# Guest access not working in moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm new to using moodle. I have downloaded Moodle 2.9 version. I'm doing the integration of drupal and moodle. to just showing the moodle courses in drupal side. I have created 10 courses in moodle among these 5 courses can be taken by guest user.

To test these functionalities I clicked the button "Login as a Guest User" in moodle login page. But it shows "Invalid user, try again".

After long searching I found that, there is no guest user record in "mdl_user" table of moodle database. Now what can I do??? Can I insert guest user details manually??????

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the things you need to check are here:https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Guest_access

It should just work, without having to create a user in the database. I think you should check the actions in the list in the link above, to see if you've done them all.

Answer (score 0):

The guest account on a new install will be id=1. Main admin is usually id=2.

Have you enabled guest access at site level?
Have you enabled auto-login for guests?
Have you allowed guest enrolment in the relevant courses?

See https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Guest_access for info.